# Where is the share price located once Apple releases its Form 10-K? Using for dividend yield calculation and need the price they used

Tags: dividends, yield, annual-report, quarterly-report

I need to find dividend yield for Apple at the release of their 2020 annual report, Form 10-K. That's it. I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? Share price or dividend yield? Please reword your question.

Comment: I had it worded better on the initial question, however the posting review said it was too subjective. I want to know how to find the share price that Apple selected upon publishing their 2020 form 10-K. Using the dividend yield ratio and other given figures.

Comment: "Using the dividend yield ratio and other given figures." — Apple's 2020 Form 10-K makes no mention of dividend yields.

Comment: Which particular figure in the 10-K are you looking to understand the derivation of?

Answer (score 1):

Formula for trailing dividend yield: dividend per share divided by share price.

The dividend per share can be found in the financial statements, while the share price can be found from financial data websites (e.g. Yahoo Finance).

To calculate the current (trailing) dividend yield, you need the current share price. Share price is always fluctuating, so even if a dividend yield is somehow mentioned in the financial statements, it would not be the *current* dividend yield of the stock.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm asking for the share price. it is understood that the share price is always fluctuating however when Apple publishes their financials, they select a share price. I want to know how to work backward to obtain the share price using given figures in the statements please.

Comment: @ewbrowning "when Apple publishes their financials, they select a share price" — Citation needed.

Comment: I suppose I'm missing something. How can I work backwards to find the share price then? Use earnings per share?

Comment: Honestly every time i come on stackexchange and ask a question, I get crucified. Hilarious. I guess I'll just quit and go dig holes for a living.

Comment: @ewbrowning Please be patient. I'm really trying to understand your confusion. I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. There is no "crucifixion".

Comment: @ewbrowning In general, financial statements do not deal with share prices. In general, financial statements can be prepared without knowing share prices. Consider the case of private companies, which have no public market for their shares. Private companies also produce financial statements.

Comment: P/E Ratio = Earnings per Share / Price per Share
This is the P/E ratio formula. How does one determine the price per share from a Form 10-K? How can one use figures inside of the published financials to determine this price?

Comment: @ewbrowning Form 10-K does not deal with P/E ratios. Apple's Form 10-K makes no mention of P/E ratios or any other financial ratios that requires the share price.

Comment: You're right, however the homework question is to determine the PE ratio using Apple's2020 annual report. However if I don't have the share price, then i'm unable to determine the P/E

Comment: @ewbrowning "However if I don't have the share price, then i'm unable to determine the P/E" — Therefore, the solution is to get the share price from an external source, so that you can calculate the P/E ratio.

Comment: I did that before coming here, this is the last stop. I thought there was something else I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

In your question:

> I need to find dividend yield for apple at the release of their 2020
> annual report, form 10-K. That's it. I can't find it anywhere.

You are looking in the annual report for the share price so you can calculate the dividend yield. You are expecting that the company uses a expected share price to set the dividend.

But you have it backwards.

Most if not all companies don't use dividend yield to set their dividend. The yield calculated is just a byproduct of the dividend amount and the current price. The corporation doesn't control the current price of a share of their stock. They decide how much of retained earning they will return to the shareholders, when setting the dividend per share.

They make this decision to set the amount of money that will be returned at a moment unrelated to the filing of the annual report. These reports take time to produce, so if if the board did vote to set the yield this way it would never match reality, because the price per share is always changing.

From the comments:

> I'm not sure how to answer this homework question if we are asked to
> determine the P/E from 2020

To get the share price on a particular date there are literally hundreds of websites that will give you the daily close of individual stocks, mutual funds, and indexes going back years.  Pick a date, get the closing price.

Comment: You are correct on the assumption that they select a share price to set the dividend. thank you for the clarity. I'm not sure how to answer this homework question if we are asked to determine the P/E from 2020

Answer (score 1):

To answer the *real* question, here's how I would approach the homework problem as a student

1. Ask the professor what share price to use (or maybe what date's closing price to use).
2. If you get no answer, I would use the closing price for the ex-div date of the dividend, and qualify the DY by adding "as of DD/MM close of trading" to be explicit about what share price *you* used. To me, the point of the question is to calculate (and probably apply) the dividend yield, so the date used is not the primary component.

All other answers are correct